# How to plot multiple sine waves/ summation of waves in python

Tags: python, numpy, fft

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import fft, fftfreq, ifft

#Varibles
A = 1
f = 10
t = 1/f
nss = 10
fs = nss*f
ts = 1/fs 
cycles = 1

#CREATING SINE WAVE
t1 = np.arange(0,cycles*t+ts,ts)
x = A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t1)

#PLOTTING SINE WAVE
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(t1,x, label = 'Sine Wave')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

#FFT CALCULATIONS
freqs = fftfreq(nss)
fft_vals = fft(x,n=512)
fft_vals2 = np.fft.fftshift(fft_vals)
freqs = np.linspace(-fs/2,fs/2,len(fft_vals2))
#mask = freqs > 0 
#fft_theo = 2.0*np.abs(fft_vals/nss)

#Plotting fft values
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(freqs, fft_vals2, label= "Raw fft Values")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
```

so i have this code for one sine wave, that finds the FFT of sine wave and plots it however i want to be plot multiple sine waves/ the summation and display the FFT of that. I'm mainly confused on how you would code it for a set amount of cycles, rather than a random amount of cycles. [This is the output i would like however instead of multiple cycles on the original signal i would like to plot a set amount of cycles that is declarable at the start of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGqEL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use a for loop. Here, the loop represents `cycle=1,2,3,4,...,9,10`, but you can change it to modify whatever variables you want:

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import fft, fftfreq, ifft


fig, ax = plt.subplots(10, 2, figsize=(40,40))
for i in range(10):
    #Varibles
    A = 1
    f = 10
    t = 1/f
    nss = 10
    fs = nss*f
    ts = 1/fs 
    cycles = i + 1

    #CREATING SINE WAVE
    t = np.arange(0,cycles*t+ts,ts)
    x = A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

    #PLOTTING SINE WAVE
    ax[i][0].plot(t,x, label='Sine Wave')
    ax[i][0].grid(True)

    #FFT CALCULATIONS
    freqs = fftfreq(nss)
    fft_vals = fft(x,n=512)
    fft_vals2 = np.fft.fftshift(fft_vals)
    freqs = np.linspace(-fs/2,fs/2,len(fft_vals2))
    #mask = freqs > 0 
    #fft_theo = 2.0*np.abs(fft_vals/nss)

    #Plotting fft values
    ax[i][1].plot(freqs, fft_vals2, label= "Raw fft Values")
    ax[i][1].grid(True)
    fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello thank you for your response however, im trying to add multiple waves together first so lets say we have `x1 = A1*np.sin(2*pi*f*t)
x2 = A2*np.sin(2*pi*f*t)
x3 = A3*np.sin(2*pi*f*t)` as the three waves and then i do X_total = x1 + x2 +x3 how would i do that for a set cycle and then print the FFT too?

Comment: @Sam I am still confused about what you are trying to achieve. Please edit your original post, and give a better explanation for what you're trying to do. An example output would be helpful.